# Layout diferente em outro dispositivo

Tags: android, android-layout

Meu layout fica diferente em dispositivos pequenos, ja tentei adicionar um `ScrollView` para solucionar esse problema e não obtive resultados.

Segue os `prints` do aplicativo rodando em dispositivos diferentes:

**<sub>Resolução 720 x 1280</sub>**

[image]

**<sub>Resolução 320 x 480</sub>**

[image]

Como vocês podem ver, os números ficaram um em cima do outro.

Segue meu xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context=".HomeActivity$PlaceholderFragment">

    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        >

        <ScrollView
            android:id="@+id/scrollViewContent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <RelativeLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content">

                <RadioGroup
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:id="@+id/rgDificuldade"
                    android:background="@drawable/background_infos"
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:orientation="vertical">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="25sp"
                        android:text="Escolha a dificuldade:" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:id="@+id/rbFácil"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:text="@string/string_facio" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/string_medio"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:id="@+id/rbMedio" />

                    <RadioButton
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:text="@string/string_dificil"
                        android:textSize="20sp"
                        android:id="@+id/rbDificil" />
                </RadioGroup>


                <RelativeLayout
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:minHeight="44sp"
                    android:layout_marginTop="5sp"
                    android:layout_below="@+id/rgDificuldade"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutAttempts">

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:background="@drawable/heart_attempts"
                        android:text="0"
                        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
                        android:gravity="center"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="3px"
                        android:id="@+id/txtQuantidadeTentativas" />

                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:minHeight="44sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutCronometro"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayoutAttempts"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayoutAttempts"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayoutAttempts">

                    <Chronometer
                        android:textSize="18sp"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/cronometroCarregarTentativa"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgViewLighting"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewLighting"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgViewLighting"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
                        android:textColor="#999999" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imgViewLighting"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"

                        android:background="@drawable/lightning"
                        android:contentDescription="Energia" />
                </RelativeLayout>

                <RelativeLayout
                    android:padding="10sp"
                    android:minHeight="44sp"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="2sp"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutXp"
                    android:layout_alignTop="@+id/relativeLayoutCronometro"
                    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/relativeLayoutCronometro"
                    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/relativeLayoutCronometro">

                    <TextView
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/txtXp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewXp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgViewXp"
                        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp"
                        android:textColor="#999999"
                        android:text="200/5000"
                        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/imgViewXp" />

                    <ImageView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:id="@+id/imgViewXp"
                        android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
                        android:background="@drawable/star_xp"
                        android:contentDescription="Energia" />

                    <TextView
                        android:textColor="#999999"
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
                        android:text="LV 0"
                        android:id="@+id/txtLvl"
                        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/imgViewXp"
                        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imgViewXp"
                        android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imgViewXp"
                        android:layout_marginLeft="-5dp" />
                </RelativeLayout>
            </RelativeLayout>
        </ScrollView>
    </RelativeLayout>
    <!--Botoes -->
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutBotoes"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        >

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:id="@+id/txtDicas"
            android:text="aaaa"
            android:layout_marginBottom="54dp"
            android:layout_above="@+id/etNumeroDigitado"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/etNumeroDigitado"
            android:background="@drawable/shape_camponumero"
            android:layout_above="@+id/btnUm"
            android:padding="8dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="#000000"
            android:enabled="false"
            android:inputType="number"
            android:typeface="monospace"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <Button
            android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
            android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="0"
            android:id="@+id/btnZero"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

        <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Ok"
        android:id="@+id/btnEnter"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="8"
        android:id="@+id/btnOito"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnEnter"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="5"
        android:id="@+id/btnCinco"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnOito"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="2"
        android:id="@+id/btnDois"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnCinco"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:singleLine="false" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="7"
        android:id="@+id/btnSete"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnZero" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="9"
        android:id="@+id/btnNove"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnZero"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="4"
        android:id="@+id/btnQuatro"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCinco"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="1"
        android:id="@+id/btnUm"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnDois"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="3"
        android:id="@+id/btnTres"
        android:layout_above="@+id/btnCinco"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="6"
        android:id="@+id/btnSeis"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnCinco"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />

    <Button
        android:background="@drawable/button_bgpressed"
        android:textColor="@drawable/button_textcolorpressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Apagar"
        android:id="@+id/btnApagar"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/btnZero"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Se possível, dê uma resposta alterando meu código.

Answer (score 4):

Olá você pode construir seu apk com multiplos layouts, assim fica mais facil adaptar a cada tela tanto para um celular ou um tablet.

Basta colocar o mesmo layout em cada pasta e alterar de acordo com a disposição que desejar em cada tela, ex na pasta **layout-small** pode colocar menos itens ou até remover os que estão atrapalhando a tela e em uma tela grando no caso do **layout-xlarge** pode adicionar novos itens ou atalhos para outras operações. Faça o teste e vai ver que é bem simples.

```
 res/layout/my_layout.xml             // layout for normal screen size ("default")
 res/layout-small/my_layout.xml       // layout for small screen size
 res/layout-large/my_layout.xml       // layout for large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge/my_layout.xml      // layout for extra large screen size
 res/layout-xlarge-land/my_layout.xml // layout for extra large in landscape orientation

 res/drawable-mdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for medium density
 res/drawable-hdpi/my_icon.png        // bitmap for high density
 res/drawable-xhdpi/my_icon.png       // bitmap for extra high density
```

Manifest

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true" 
      android:normalScreens="true" 
      android:largeScreens="true"
      android:xlargeScreens="true"
      android:anyDensity="true" />
```

Você pode dar uma olhada nesses links na documentação do android para entender melhor:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html
http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screendensities.html

Comment: A programação da tela`(code behind)` muda, ou não?

Comment: Apenas para complementar, [acesse ESSE LINK](https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html?utm_source=ausdroid.net), que você poderá visualizar quais as densidades e tamanhos mais usados nos aparelhos hoje...

Comment: @Exception Isso vai depender do layout, se colocar mais elementos ou remover de acordo com o layout pode ser preciso tratar estes elementos separados. Mas nada de muito impacto.